# How to generate PDF using Rotativa in Plesk hosting using ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, rotativa

I hosted my ASP.NET MVC application in a plesk hosting environment. Everything works nice but except one thing: Cannot generate PDF using Rotativa inside that environment.

This is the Error:

> This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator

[image]

I have this in my ***web.config:***

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>

    <trust level="Full" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
  </system.web>
  
  <system.webServer>

    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    
    <!--<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <remove statusCode="404" />
      <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/PageNotFound" />
    </httpErrors>-->
    
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.0" newVersion="4.1.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  
  
  <entityFramework>
    <contexts>
      <context type="CapaBaseDeDatos.Data.Context, CapaBaseDeDatos">
        <databaseInitializer type="CapaBaseDeDatos.Data.DatabaseInitializer, CapaBaseDeDatos" />
      </context>
    </contexts>

    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

My local server runs great when generating PDF using Rotativa library in ASP.NET MVC, but cannot run it in the plesk hosting. I could not find solutions in the internet.

Do I have to configure my plesk hosting?

PD: I am using a shared hosting environment.

Comment: Try removing all the tags inside the system.codedom tag and add
<trust level="Full"/>
or ask your hosting provider to check Trust Level and set it to "Full".

Comment: Done, but did not work.